# Simple way to get height for Longitude/Latitude coordinates list from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gps

Is there a simple way to get a list of heights from Google Maps for a list of Longitude/Latitude?

input:

```
Latitude   Longitude  
32.111362   34.807575
32.111362   34.807575
32.111362   34.807575
32.11136    34.807606
32.11136    34.807606
32.111343   34.80759
.....        .......
```

Output:

```
Latitude   Longitude      Height 
32.111362   34.807575       35
32.111362   34.807575       35
32.111362   34.807575       34
.....        .......        ..
```

I've been searching for a simple way to do this for a few days but came up with nothing (my coding experience is with MATLAB and Python).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to do it easily is with the site:

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/elevation.html

Using this site with your personal Google API key works great!

Answer (score 1):

There are some Elevation Models for the whole world that was gathered by the SRTM mission (public domain data) complemented with interpolation and other dataset to fill up gaps, that can be found here:
http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3.html

It is not saved in the exact format that you want, but it can be easily transformed from HGT format to tabular with some parsing. For example, for Python, this library worked like charm: https://github.com/gmalt/hgtparser